# how to insert values into specific columns and rows?

Tags: shell

e.g. cat testing_file.txt gives

**input:**

```
ABC
ABC
```

**expected output:**

```
ACB
CBA
```

**Question:**

1) how to insert values into specific columns and rows?

Comment: temp = 'head -1 $filename | cut -c22-25' is capable of extracting column 22 to 25 for the first line of the file and store it.

Comment: This is a specification not a question.

Comment: sorry Will rephrase it. Just stating the entire scenario for better understanding for the question.

Comment: @user1872384  your expect output is not same as you described in comment. `1234567000  34567890 890567890     ---> replace 234 with 890 and 890 with 000 ` I do see 234 and 890 is there, not get replaced.

Comment: Hey Kent, thank you for your justification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this have to be done in Shell? It's straightforward in Perl:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

while (<>)
{
  unless (/^<234>/)
  {
    my ($from_pos, $length, $to_pos)
        = /^<!!!>/ ? (21, 4, 6) : (7, 3, 21);
    my $old = substr $_, $from_pos, $length, '0' x $length;
    substr $_, $to_pos, $length, $old;
  }

  print;
}
```

Note that `substr` is zero-based, so the `$from_pos` is either 21 or 7, not 22 or 8.